# Only having one view autorotate in xcode?

Tags: iphone, xcode, view, autorotate, parentviewcontroller

Ok so I currently have 3 views and I need only one of them to autorotate to any orientation while the rest stay in portrait.  Right now my set up is a splashviewcontroller fades into view A, and inside view A is a button to switch to view B.  All I want is for view B to be able to rotate to any orientation.

When I return YES for shouldautorotatetointerfaceorientation in the splashviewcontroller, every view rotates because this is the parent view.  When I return portrait only in the splashview, nothing rotates even if the other views return YES.  Is there a way to only have view B rotate?  I'm willing to do it manually if you can provide code.  Thanks

Comment: How is B being added? If it is not independent (i.e. via navigation controller), this might be the problem.

Comment: @stavash so how would I make it independent?  I added by doing add UIViewController Subclass

Comment: @stavash is there a way to make an independent view without a tab bar?  Can I link to an independent view using a button?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can manually mange the rotation of any desired UIView object like so:

**EDIT:**

In the init or viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotate) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];

    [super viewDidLoad];
}

#define degreesToRadian(x) (M_PI * (x) / 180.0)

-(void)rotate{

    self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(0, 0, 0, 0);

    if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait){


        CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
        landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);

        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, 320, 480);

        [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];


    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown){


        CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(180));
        landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);

        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, 320, 480);

        [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

    } else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight){

        CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(90));

         landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
         self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, 480, 320); 


        [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];

    }else if ([UIDevice currentDevice].orientation == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft){

        CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(270));

        landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);
        self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, 480, 320); 

        [self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
    }

}
```

Comment: nothing happens when I put this in my ViewB.m.  View B is a modalviewcontroller, is there something stupid I might be doing wrong?

Comment: To make it work you will have to trigger rotate method after you catch a rotation event. Pls, check the edit in the answer

Comment: Ok, so that works perfectly, but the problem is that while the view does rotate, I have a video that plays inside a webview inside of ViewB that I need to rotate also.  Any suggestions for accomplishing this?  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Inside targets summary section, Supported Interface Orientation all items are selected except for Upside Down, so all you need to do is go to your .m file that handles the view and use this piece of code.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

This did the trick for me.