# How to hold NavigationController in subViewController orientation?

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, orientation

I have made a NavigationController structure.
FirstViewController is RootViewController, SecondViewController is a next SubViewController. Each ViewController shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation is a different(refer a following code). 
FirstViewController is only portrait available. SecondViewController all support Portrait and landscapeMode.

In FirstViewController after sth button touch, call a pushHandler. next SecondViewController is a pushed.
In SecondViewController after rotated landscape back to the FirstViewController, that orientation is too landscape.

but, I implemented each ViewController orientation different. however each ViewController not independently set orientation. why happen?

How can I viewcontroller each orientation can be set independently, to do?

If SecondViewController change the orientation of the landscapeMode. I want back to the FirstViewController still portraitMode(forever hold portraitState Anything not to be affected). 
How do I implements programmatically?

```
FirstViewController *rootViewController = [FirstViewController alloc] init];

UINavigationController *MyNavigationController = [UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:rootViewController]];
```

//**FirstViewController**

```
- (void)pushHandler
{
    SecondViewController *subViewController = [SecondViewController alloc] init];

    [[self navigationController] pushViewController:subViewController animated:YES];
    [subViewController release];
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait);
}
```

//**SecondViewController**

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{    
    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you use a `UINavigationController` for all your `UIViewControllers` whatever orientation behaviour you will set for the `UINavigationController` will be applied to all it's `children` or in otherwords objects on its stack.

Think of a `UINavigationController` as a house and `UIViewControllers` as rooms. All the rooms in the house will rotate in the same way the house. There is no way to turn a room without turning the house and other rooms.

But as always there are tricks. Look at my answer to this question [Only having one view autorotate in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8043263/277021)

Comment: I've already tried a similar code was applied. My NavigationController structure very complex because have a TabBarController, navigationItem... you're code not change navigationItem and TabBarController orientation. and          [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(rotate) name:UIDeviceOrientationDidChangeNotification object:nil];
this Notification is always respond only UIDeviceState. not related shouldAutorotateToInterface. return (interfaceOrientation == UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait); but notification always respond. so your'e code is Does not fit me.