# When rotating my viewController, the status bar doesn't rotate with the with. How to fix it?

Tags: objective-c, ios6, uiinterfaceorientation

Everyone. I've got an iOS6 ipad app to update. The problem I met is that only one view controller needs autorotate, and I don't find out the correct method to do this.

I've tried the following link and it partly helped: 
[Only having one view autorotate in xcode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8043263/only-having-one-view-autorotate-in-xcode)

But when I rotate the viewController, its status bar doesn't rotate with the view and the title of the view doesn't stay in the center as I set.

I add breakpoints in the viewController, and find that only when the device is landscape does it calls `- (void)willRotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration`.

I wonder if anyone can tell me where the bug hides and how to fix it.
Thanks in forward.

Comment: whats the status of this Question.?Is it resolved? BTW i am not getting exactly what u want.

Comment: It's a autorotation bug and has been solved. Thanks for asking. :)

Comment: it will be good if you either close this question or just put the solution and except your own answer.rest is your wish.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've solved this problem. My mistake is that I added some words below when setting the autorotation issue.

```
CGAffineTransform landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(0));
landscapeTransform = CGAffineTransformTranslate (landscapeTransform, 0.0, 0.0);

self.view.bounds = CGRectMake(self.view.bounds.origin.x, self.view.bounds.origin.y, 768, 1024);

if (isVisible == NO) return; // iOS present modal bodge
[self updateScrollViewContentViews]; // Update content views
lastAppearSize = CGSizeZero; // Reset view size tracking

[self.view setTransform:landscapeTransform];
```

I deleted these manual words and leave the following methods alone. It's done.

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskAll;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation
{
    return YES;
}
```